# How can I combine two very similar methods in java which result in two seperate ListArrays?

Tags: java, methods

I have two methods that do basically the same thing, they search in an XML file for certain elements, like corners, which are parsed to points and then inserted into an ArrayList. I would like to make the two methods into one, since they do basically the same thing. But I still want to have the two separate ArrayLists at the end.

I would also like to ask if the method are correct (I have done a lot of research) and if I can check if there are any corners and lamps in the file before reading it in. Because not every file contains these elements.

Maybe you can help me with that? Would appreciate that a lot!

Comment: If I see correctly, the only difference between the two methods is "Lampe" and "Ecke". Just create a method that accepts some sort of `String filter` parameter and call it from both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abstract the thing that varies. Pass the string passed to `ElementFilter` as an argument.

```
private ArrayList<Point2D.Float> readPositions(Element rootElement, String s) {
    ArrayList<Point2D.Float> pos = new ArrayList<>(); 
    IteratorIterable<Element> iter = rootElement.getDescendants(new ElementFilter(s));
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Element elem = iter.next(); 
        Element childX = elem.getChild("x");
        Element childY = elem.getChild("y");
        Point2D.Float lamp = new Point2D.Float(
                Float.parseFloat(childX.getText()),
                Float.parseFloat(childY.getText()));
        pos.add(lamp);
    } 
    return pos;
}
```

Call it as

```
 ArrayList<Point2D.Float> vertices = readPositions(rootElement, "Ecke"); 
 ArrayList<Point2D.Float> lamps = readPositions(rootElement, "Lampe");
```

You can rename the method and the 2nd string parameter to give a more meaningful name (I couldn't understand the problem domain fully).

Comment: Marvelous! Thank you. It's perfect. Could you tell me additionally how I can check if the element "Lampe" or "Ecke" appears in the list before I start reading it in?

Comment: (Assuming your code works) Are you asking for a more efficient way to check if an XML document has a particular string? - If yes, I'm not an expert on XML DOM parsing or manipulation

Comment: I don't mean that your code does not work. You have asked two questions here (which is to be avoided here). I hope I have answered your first part of removing duplication.

Comment: Sure you have, thank you very much! :) I may find somewhere how I can check this. Thank you for helping!